# Function $ g $ is continuous in $ 0 $ if $ f $ is differentiable in $ (0,0) $

Tags: real-analysis

Let be $ g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $ a function and $ f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R},(x,y)\mapsto y\cdot g(x) $ differentiable in $ (0,0) $. I want to show that $ g $ is continuous in $ 0 $ by contradiction.

My idea:
Because $ f $ is in $ (0,0) $ differentialbe there exists a linear map $ N:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R} $ with $ N(w)=w_2\cdot g(0) $ and an errorfunction $ R:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R} $ for all $ w=(w_1,w_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2 $ such that

$$ \begin{align} w_2\cdot g(w_1)&=f(w)=f((0,0)+w)=f((0,0))+N(w)+R(w)\\ &=0+N(w)+R(w)\\&=w_2\cdot g(0)+R(w)\end{align}$$
and $ \lim\limits_{w\to 0}\frac{R(w)}{\|w\|}=0 $.

We can write for all $ w\in \mathbb{R}^2 $: $ R(w)=w_2\cdot (g(w_1)-g(0)) $.

Now assume $ g $ is not continuous in $ 0 $. So there exists a sequence $ (w^{(1)}_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus {\{0\}} $ with $ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} g((w^{(1)}_n))\neq g(0)$. With that consider a new sequence $ ((w^{(1)}_n,w^{(2)}_n))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\setminus {\{(0,0)\}} $ with $ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (w^{(1)}_n,w^{(2)}_n)=(0,0) $.
Now I want to show with that the limit $ \lim\limits_{w\to 0}\frac{R(w)}{\|w\|}$ is not equal to $ 0 $ but I don't see it.

Comment: Actually, your statement is not true... if $g(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\neq 0\\ 1&x=0\end{cases}$, then $F$ will be differentiable at $(0,0)$, but $g$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: No. If $ f $ is in $ (0,0) $ differentiable then all directional derivatives $ \partial_vf(0,0) $ of $ f $ in $ (0,0) $ are existing. So consider $$ \partial_{(v_1,v_2)}f(0,0)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h\cdot (v_1,v_2))-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} v_2\cdot g(h\cdot v_1) $$ which doesn't exist because $ g $ (your example) is not continuous. So $ f $ is not differentiable in $ (0,0) $.

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention that $ g $ is a function of the form $ g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $. I have adjusted my upper text.

Comment: With the example I gave, if $v_1\neq 0$, $$\lim_{h\to 0}v_2g(hv_1)=\lim_{h\to 0}hv_1v_2=0,$$ which obviously exist... and if $v_1=0$, then it will give $v_2$ which exist as well...